# cannot recover data from DBMS with RMI client

Tags: java, mysql, ejb, wildfly, rmi

I have an EJB 3.2 project that I integrated into my wildfly server. Then I interrogate my project using an RMI client, the tables are generated and the addition in the DBMS goes without problem but when I try to recover from the database I have this error message:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: Failed to read response
    at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBClientChannel$MethodInvocation$MethodCallResultProducer.getResult(EJBClientChannel.java:1221)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:592)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:172)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:938)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:177)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:112)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.listeEmployes(Unknown Source)
    at com.clientbanque.programme.ClientBanque.main(ClientBanque.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:123)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:104)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1022)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1355)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:220)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1853)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1767)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1395)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:220)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadCollectionObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:176)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readCollectionData(RiverUnmarshaller.java:850)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:726)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:205)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBClientChannel$MethodInvocation$MethodCallResultProducer.getResult(EJBClientChannel.java:1202)
    ... 22 more
```

If you can tell me where the problem is coming from. I will be grateful
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the ejb call results contain reference to hibernate-core class. Try adding a jboss module dependency for hibernate-core module to your project.

For example, in your project WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml, or META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml,

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```